# What does <() do in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, subprocess

In [a post's](https://superuser.com/questions/25302/how-to-join-files-on-the-command-line-without-creating-temp-files) answer on superuser.com, we see that

```
join <(sort abc) <(sort bcd)
```

will sort files abc and bcd before sending them to join. This leads to a programming question, better suited for stackoverflow.

How does this work? What exactly is this <() construct? What's it called?

If (sort abc) is a legal call that runs sort on abc and returns output, why do we need the `<`?

That is, the following two lines are equivalent

```
(sort abc) | join - <(sort bcd)
join <(sort abc) <(sort bcd)
```

but

```
join (sort abc) (sort bcd)
```

is a syntax error. Please clue me in!

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of reading the fine manual for a shell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is called process substitution.

`<(`*`list`*`)` is a single syntax construct, the '<' character is not a separate symbol in this case. It executes *list* and provides its output as sort of a file (not a standard redirection) to the command.

It is equivalent to running (except it uses pipes instead of temporary files when possible):

```
sort abc > /tmp/1
sort bcd > /tmp/2
join /tmp/1 /tmp/2
```

Note that the output of both sorts are provided as filenames to join, not as standard redirections.

`(`*`list`*`)` is a different construct, for a different purpose. It simply creates a subshell that executes *list*, providing its standard descriptors to the parent shell.

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) is the relevant part in the bash manual.

Answer (score 6):

`<(`*`command`*`)` is a **Process Substitution** (see the according section in `man bash`). Basically *command* is run and its output is fed to a named pipe (FIFO), and the whole construct is then replaced by the name of the pipe, thus resulting in `join /dev/fd/`*`x`* `/dev/fd/`*`y`*.